# Create rule to make request only contain certain keys

Tags: php, laravel, validation, lumen

I am using the Lumen Framework, which utilizes the [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)
I wanted to create a Validator Rule to make the Request->input() json only contain specific keys at the root like "domain" and "nameservers". Not more and not less.

Example passing the rule:

```
{
    "domain":"domain.tld",
    "nameservers":
        {...}
}
```

Example not passing the rule:

```
{
    "domain":"domain.tld",
    "nameservers":
        {...},
    "Hack":"executeSomething()"
}
```

I tried to use to use several default validation rules to achieve this but wasnt successful.
My approach was now to put the request in another array like this 
    $checkInput['input'] = $request->all();
to make the validator validate the "root" keys.

Now this is my Approach:

**create the validator**

```php
        $checkInput['input'] = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($checkInput, [
            'input' => [
                'onlyContains:domain,nameservers'
            ],
        ]);
```

**creating the rule**

```php
        Validator::extend('onlyContains', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){

            $input = $validator->getData();
            $ok = 0;
            foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
                if (Arr::has($input, $attribute . '.' . $value)) {
                    $ok++;
                }
            }
            if (sizeof(Arr::get($input, $attribute)) - $ok > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

It seems i got the desired result, but i am asking if there is maybe smarter solution to this with the default rules provided by Laravel/Lumen.

Comment: I think extending the Validator is probably the neatest way of doing this. I'm not aware of anything standard in the Validator that can do what you're asking. 
All in all, it looks like you've chosen the best approach to this there is.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a blacklisting approach blocking out fields that are not intended. A simple approach, that is utilized a lot, is to only fetch out the validated. Also you are trying to do logic, that goes against normal validation logic, to do it a field at a time.

This is also a good time, to learn about `FormRequest` and how you can get that logic, into a place where it makes more sense.

```
public function route(MyRequest $request) {
    $input = $request->validated();
}
```

With this approach, you will only ever have the validated fields in the $input variable. As an extra bonus, this approach will make your code way easier to pick up by other Laravel developers. Example form request below.

```
public class MyRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'domain' => ['required', 'string'], 
            'nameservers' => ['required', 'array'], 
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use prohibited rule.
For eg:

```
$allowedKeys = ['domain', 'nameservers'];
$inputData =  $request->all();

$inputKeys = array_keys($inputData);

$diffKeys = array_diff($inputKeys, $allowedKeys);

$rules = [];
foreach($diffKeys as $value) {
    $rules[$value] = ['prohibited'];
}
```